# Sublime Text 3 find and replace in multiple files

Tags: file, replace, find, sublimetext3

I want to find and replace code in multiple files.

Does anyone know if the feature "find and replace in multiple files" in Sublime Text 3 is gone?

It used to be a feature for ST2 (shift-command-F), see screenshots ST2 and ST3.

Or is there a other way to do this?

[image: Sublime Text 2]

[image: Sublime Text 3]

Comment: Build 3126 contains this feature as usual.

Comment: Thanks will look into too that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The option is still there, but because you're using a custom theme the bar needs to be taller for you to see the entire contents of the panel.

You can grab the top of the panel and stretch it up so that everything is visible and then back down as far as it will go to make it compact again.

You only have to do this once; Sublime remembers the height of the panel and will use it next time (which is why it uses the incorrect height when you switch to a theme that makes everything in the panel taller).

Comment: Cheers mate, that was the case! Didn't notice that at all ;-)